# Lowest value is always 0 in 2d array

Tags: java

New guy here trying 2D arrays. I have these codes but whenever I run it, the lowest value would always end up with 0 even if I input non-zero digits. Any idea how to fix this?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TwoDArrayActivity {
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        // declaration of array
        int a[][] = new int[3][3];  

        int i = 0; // rows
        int j = 0; // columns
        String display = ""; 

        int low = a[i][j];
        
        for(i=0; i < a.length; i++) {   // count the number of rows
            
            for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) {      // count the number of columns
                a[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a Number to Array [" + i + "]" + "[" + j + "]"));
                
                if(a[i][j] < low) 
                    low = a[i][j];
                display = display + a[i][j] + "     ";
            } // end of inner for
            
            display = display + "\n"; //new line 
        } // end of outer for
           
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Values in Array\n" + display + "Lowest value is " + low, "Values in Array", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } // end of method
} // end of class
```

Comment: You initialize low as `int low = a[i][j];`, meaning that it's 0 at the start. Unless you input lower (=negative) numbers, it will stay at 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace :

```java
int low = a[i][j];
```

with :

```java
int low = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// declaration of array
int a[][] = new int[3][3];
```

The issue is here, when you instantiate the array it automatically fills every emtry with 0, as this is the equivalent of the undefined value for an integer type. eg.

```
new int[3][3]
>> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Therefore your `low` variable always has the value 0 and is never replaced by something lower

Comment: I also think this is the case. See [Default array values in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-array-values-in-java/).

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize an array implicitly in Java, the memory gets set to `null`, `0`, `0L`, `0.0f`, `false`, or `0.0`, etc, as appropriate for the datatype.

That means that your statement `int low = a[i][j];` is setting `low` to an initial value of zero. All further comparisons will be against that, so your only chance to change that value is to enter a negative number, like `-1`.

You can add a test to your loop to initialize `low` with the first element of the loop you get:

```
if((i == 0 && j == 0) || a[i][j] < low)
```

Another option is to initialize `low` to the largest possible integer instead of implicit zero. In this simple example, that's probably the simplest approach to take:

```
int low = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

A third option is to add a boolean flag:

```
int low = ...;
boolean isFirst = true;

...

    if(isFirst || a[i][j] < low)
        ...
    isFirst = False;
```

Comment: The explanation is correct, but your solution is not good. Why should it be initialized to `a[i][j]` when `a` does not contain useful values? Initializing it with a big value is a far better approach.

Comment: @f1sh. Both are valid approaches, and I included them. For this simple case, you are correct that Integer.MAX_VALUE is probably the way to go, but the other options are valid too in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

You have to input negative numbers for it to change.
Otherwise, you can change it to

```
if(a[i][j] < low) 
    low = a[i][j];
```

but the name low wouldn't make sense anymore (it will be a "max").